# How to send function parameters of fucntion in exception

Tags: c#, android

I realized that the app I am working on generate quite a few errors. Pretty much everytime an error happens it's caught and logged, but sadly, none of them log the values that were sent (that would be useful to debug).

Is there an easy solution that I could add to also send all parameters of through the log?

Here's an example of what I have.

```
public static async Task<InventoryItem> GetTaskInventory(string labeladresse)
        {
            InventoryItem result = null;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    IDeliveryService client = Common.GetDeliveryService();
                    result = client.GetLineTaskInventory(labeladresse);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.Data.Add("parameters", $"labeladresse = {labeladresse}");
                    LogError(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                }
            }).ConfigureAwait(false); ;

            return result;
        }
```

But I would like to change the ex.Data.Add part to something more generic, since I'm probably going to put it quite often, I'd like to be able to use a line I can more copy paste where needed.

Imagine something like: ex.Data.Add(function.parameters[]);

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy way to do that. You can obtain the current method youre working in by getting the relevant `StackFrame`, but this does not give you access to the current values of any variables. Moreover, this kindof information is not accessable in a Release configuration anyway, meaning this is basically impossible in any non local environment. I know it seems a hassle but being careful with what you log will drastically improve your level of debugging, so it's worth to just log per instance imo

Comment: Welp, if that is the case, I got 70 extra boring lines of code to write.
Thanks @Glubus

Comment: Tbh I've never really done this myself so if you'd reeaally needed it I would look into it way more. But if its just a couple of lines of code I'd just bite the bullet once and then maintain it in new code.

Comment: or make a single helper method eg LogErrorWithMethodParameters(......)

Comment: You could use reflection to get the function argument names. Off the top of my head, I don't know how you would get the values. This does not seem like the correct approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Either you have to write your own method or use Reflection.